# jsfx filter bank frequency response issue

Tags: filters, filter-bank

I am probably going about this completely wrong, but I'm trying to implement a filter bank in reaper's JSFX as follows: First, split the spectrum into half (via aritmetic and a fo-lpf), then split each half in half, and etc until I have 32 bands at the right half of a buffer. The problem is, listening to the intermediary results, I seem to run into an issue when I compare the 4/8 block with the 5/8 block (buffer positions 11 and 12) - the 4/8 block sounds like the frequency content has a higher mean then the 5/8 block.

Am I going about a filter bank in the wrong method? The type of filter used is a simple one pole first order IIR.

```
@init
coeffs = memalloc(64);
Lbands = memalloc(64);
Rbands = memalloc(64);
top_frac = min(0.45, 20000/srate);
top_frac = min(0.45, 1500/srate);
bot_frac = 1500/srate;
bot_frac = 80/srate;

bc = 1;
loop(5,
    bi = bc;
    fi = 1;
    loop(bc,
        frac1 = (fi / bc / 2);
        frac = bot_frac + (top_frac - bot_frac) * frac1;
        coeffs[bi] = exp(-2*$pi*frac);
        bi += 1;
        fi += 2;
    );
    bc *= 2;
);

@sample
L = spl0;
R = spl1;
Lbands[1] = L;
Rbands[1] = R;
bc = 1;
loop(5,
    bi = bc;
    fi = 1;
    loop(bc,
        sampL = Lbands[bi];
        sampR = Rbands[bi];
        Lbands[2*bi] = sampL + (Lbands[2*bi] - sampL) * coeffs[bi];
        Rbands[2*bi] = sampR + (Rbands[2*bi] - sampR) * coeffs[bi];
        Lbands[2*bi+1] = sampL - Lbands[2*bi];
        Rbands[2*bi+1] = sampR - Rbands[2*bi];
        bi += 1;
        fi += 2;
    );
    bc *= 2;
);
```

of note: linear phase is not desired, and perfect reconstruction is nice to have, but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking it through, I've come up with the following solution:

Instead of having a complicated setup, let residue = the original signal. Repeat N-1 times: take the low pass filter, output that sample, and then subtract to find the residue. Finally, residue contains band N (index N-1). This seems simple enough to me, and it works for my purpose.